# pandas locate value from 2 lists and store 3º value

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I've 2 lists of items like this:

List 1:

```
Type;Color;Weight;
Apples;Red;15gr;
Bananas;Yellow;10gr;
Oranges;Orange;15gr;
```

List 2:

```
Type;Color;Price;
Bananas;Yellow;1;
Oranges;Orange;0.85;
Apples;Red;0.50;
```

What i need to acomplish is add to the first list a new column with the price values of the 2 list:

List 1:

```
Type;Color;Weight;Price;
Apples;Red;15gr;1;
Bananas;Yellow;10gr;0.85;
Oranges;Orange;15gr;0.50;

#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
firstList = 'list1.csv'
secondList = 'list2.csv'

class Fruits:
    def Unify(self):
        List1 = pd.read_csv(firstList,encoding='utf-8',delimiter=';')
        List2 = pd.read_csv(secondList,encoding='utf-8',delimiter=',') # Yes, delimiter it's different
        for row in List1:
            if List1[List1.Type.isin[List2['Type']]] == True:
                List1['Price'] = pd.Series(List2['Price'], index=data.index)
                print List1['Type'], List1['Price']
Test = Fruits()
Test.Unify()
```

But when i run the code it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Any idea how i can fix it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) if need match types with colors and only common columns names for join `on` parameter should be omit:

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2)
#if more common columns names
#df = pd.merge(df1,df2, on=['Type','Color'])
print (df)
      Type   Color Weight  Price
0   Apples     Red   15gr   0.50
1  Bananas  Yellow   10gr   1.00
2  Oranges  Orange   15gr   0.85
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
joined = List1.merge(List2, how='inner', on=['Type','Color'])[[0,1,2,4]]
```